# Why does this print out 21 and not 11?

Tags: java, modulo

The code I wrote was meant to take the sum of the digits of an integer number, e.g. 143 gives out 8, 020341 give out 10.

[This is the code I wrote for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX9iI.png)

I intended for this to print out 11 but it gives me 21 instead. It works fine if the first digit isn't a 0, I'm not sure on how to make it so that it works with 0 in the first digit.

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The literal `01235` is actually the number 669 (-> 21).  `020341` is 8417 (-> 20).  They are octal literals.

Comment: An integer with leading zero represent a number in octal not in decimal. 012345 ocal equals 5349 in decimal. And 9+4+3+5 = 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the leading 0, your int is an octal.

```
System.out.println(012345 == 12345); // false
```